# How to get PostgreSQL restore to accept ";" and "\N" in data as part of strings?

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

Did a pg_dump on PG 8.4 and trying to restore on PG 9.1.

Some of my data contains semi-colons, as in:

```
351717»·0»2014-04-28 13:26:23.119418»·2014-04-28 13:26:23.119418»·94642.000»1»0.000»LEASE»
1997-03-17 21:00:00»MACA»·0.000»0.000»0.000»
In favour of JOHN SMITH and BETTY SMITH; as joint tenants, for the term of 30 years 
commencing on 86-08-01.»·\N»·\N»·NOT_APPLICABLE»·\N»·f»f»\N»·\N»·\N»·\N»·\N»·\N»·0.00000»\N»
```

But, psql restore is choking on the semi-colons, and getting confused by the newlines (\N);

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "as"
LINE 1: as joint tenants, for the term of 30 years commencing on 86-...
        ^
invalid command \N
invalid command \N
invalid command \N
```

How do I tell psql to properly interpret this data?

Thanks,
Tim

Comment: How specifically did you dump that data? Looks like it might be a binary format that `psql` won't understand.

Comment: Look at the error. Is that semicolon really on line 1? If not, have you changed line-endings (e.g. *nix vs Windows). Also - why aren't you using the standard -Fc format for the dump and pg_resore?

Answer (score 2):

@[Richard Huxton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1029453/richard-huxton) - Thanks for the tip in the right direction. The *-Fc* option was what I needed, and using *pg_restore* instead of piping the restore file to *psql*.

So, I ended up doing:

```
pg_dump polar -f polar_20140930 -Fc
```

and a restore by doing

```
$ createdb polar
$ pg_restore -d polar_20140930 -d polar -Fc
```

and that worked nicely.

As an earlier test, and just for reference here, I tried using the --column-inserts flag:

```
pg_dump --column-inserts polar -f polar_20140929.sql
```

Then a restore by piping the output to psql:

```
psql -e polar < polar_20140929.sql > polar_restore.txt
```

This approach also worked, but as the documentation warned, the restore operation took forever (nearly 3 hours for an 80 MB sql dump). Still, it got around the problem I had with ";" and "\N".

So, two solutions, but Richard's pointer about the *-Fc* option was the ticket.

Thanks so much,
Tim